# How to determine the law of a random variable?

Tags: probability

> In a game, a player rolls a die until he gets a total of at least 6.
>
> If the die shows 6, the game is over, else, for example if on the first roll the die shows 5, the player knows that on the next roll the game will be over.
>
> - N is the random variable that represents the number of rolls.
> - $r_1$ is the random variable that represents the number that the die shows on a the first roll.
>
>   1. What is the law of $r_1$.
>   2. What is the conditional law of $r_1$, knowing $r_1 \in \{3,6 \}$
>
>      ---

1. $r_1$ takes values from $1$ to $6$. The probability of $r_1$ of being any number from $1$ to $6$ is $p(r_1) = \frac{1}{6}$. But I don't understand what we mean by determining the law of $r_1$.
2. The same issue, I understand the conditional probability and I know its formula but I don't know the meaning of determining the law.

   ---

Comment: Well, what is the probability that the game takes exactly one turn?  Exactly two turns?  And so on.

Comment: @lulu That depends on the result of each roll. Can you elaborate more please? thank you.

Comment: Well, given that the first roll is either $3$ or $6$, the probability that the game ends on the first roll is $\frac 12$.  Thus $P(N=1\,| \, r_1\in \{3,6\})=\frac 12$.  Now, can you compute $P(N=2\,| \, r_1\in \{3,6\})$?

Comment: @lulu Given that the first roll is either $3$ or $5$, the second roll needs to be 3, the probability of the next of the roll to be $3$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.

If $r_1 = 6$, the game is over on the first roll and the probability is $1$.

Comment: I don't understand.  If $r_1=3$ then the second roll does not need to be another $3$ to end the game.  It could be any of $3,4,5,6$.

Comment: Your goal is to compute $P(N=i\,| \, r_1\in \{3,6\})$ for $i\in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$.  I did $i=1$ for you.  You should be able to convince yourself that the answer is $0$ if $i≥4$.  So all you have to do is to handle the cases $i=2,3$.  Just write out all the cases if you can't think of anything else!

Comment: @lulu That's correct! so the probability is $\frac{4}{6}$

Comment: No...you need to multiply by $\frac 12$ because you need the first roll to be $3$, not $6$.

Comment: @lulu Why do I need to multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ ? The probability that on the next roll the game will finish is $\frac{4}{6}$ because any of $3,4,5,6$ as a result will end the game. Where am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Because you need the first roll to be a $3$ and the probability of that is $\frac 12$ (given that we are told it was either $3$ or $6$).

Comment: @lulu One last question, if I wanted to answer the question 1, I need to make a table and determine $P (N = i \space | \space r_1 \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \})$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$ ? 

Like instead of multiplying by $\frac{1}{2} $, this time is going to be $\frac{1}{6}$ Is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  Without additional information, $r_i$ can be any of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with equal probability.

Comment: @lulu Thank you so much for your help.